# Como usar una tabla para seleccionar las columnas de otra

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

hola tengo una tabla con una columna: nombre
ej:

```
| nombre | 
| -------|
|  Alex  |
|  Maria |
|  Juan  |
```

y otra tabla con X columnas entre ellas Alex Maria Juan
con datos como las veces que han ido a las oficinas:

```
| oficina  | Alex| Maria | Juan| Nombre1 | Nombre2 | Nombre3|
| -------  |-----| ------|-----|---------| --------|--------|
| BCN      |  2  |  1    |  9  |    2    |    6    |    9   |
| Madrid   |  3  |  3    |  4  |    5    |    1    |   10   |
| Sevilla  |  2  |  1    |  1  |    8    |    0    |    5   |
```

como puedo obtener únicamente los datos de los nombres de la primera tabla?
osea esta:

```
| oficina  | Alex| Maria | Juan|
| -------  |-----| ------|-----|
| BCN      |  2  |  1    |  9  |
| Madrid   |  3  |  3    |  4  |
| Sevilla  |  2  |  1    |  1  |
```

Comment: Qúe has intentado?

Comment: Buenas la tabla de nombres, sale de una query mia, he intentado poner esa query dentro del select pero no ha funcionado

Comment: Y cuál es la query?

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir toda la información que haga falta y que te pidan en los comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

Me da la impresion que la tabla 2 esta mal armada.
No indicas como es el problema pero para hacer el join en la tabla dos quitaria las columnas de Alex| Maria | Juan| Nombre1 | Nombre2 | Nombre3 etc y crearia una nueva columna "Nombre" con los valores Alex, Maria, Juan, Nombre1, Nombre2, Nombre3

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo literalmente lo que planteas (o bien, como te entendí), sería algo de esta manera

```
SELECT `Oficina`, `Alex`, `Maria`, `juan` FROM `oficina`;
```

Ya si no es lo que buscas, recomiendo que plantees la situación un poco más desglosada además del avance que hayas realizado.